# Understanding a negative offset of a registry data reference to a dll file

Tags: windows, dll, registry, firewall, offset

I almost have an answer to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337343/windows-7-firewall-modify-group-items-from-command-line), but I need help.

The Windows Firewall Rules (Vista and up) are stored in the Registry `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules`

Example rule: `v2.0|Action=Allow|Active=TRUE|Dir=Out|Protocol=6|Profile=Domain|RPort=5722|App=%SystemRoot%\system32\dfsr.exe|Svc=Dfsr|Name=@FirewallAPI.dll,-32257|Desc=@FirewallAPI.dll,-32260|EmbedCtxt=@FirewallAPI.dll,-32252|Edge=FALSE|`

The field I need to decode is `EmbedCtxt=@FirewallAPI.dll,-32252`

I think it references `C:\WINDOWS\System32\FirewallAPI.dll`, but I can't figure out how the number works. The file is ~400KB depending.

I tried a few variations like pretending it was an unsigned `short`, pretending it was not negative, pretending it was offset from the end, but they did not look right when I arrived at the location with my hex editor.

Could somebody give me their ideas? What this number might mean? I hardly know anything about DLL files. It could even be a section number for all I know.

I also tried searching the text for the expected output, but it seems it is neither byte per character, nor is it UTF-16, either that or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: It represents a string resource ID, negative to make it an absolute number instead of a relative one.  You'll need to use the winapi to read it, LoadLibrary + LoadString + FreeLibrary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raymond covers it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101018122506/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/05/10007461.aspx). Positive numbers are resource indices. Negative numbers (once you've removed the minus sign) are resource identifiers.